# MySQL join same table display rows in columns way (complicated)

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I would like to join the same table 4 times to get columns way to display, I am not sure is it possible do in 1 single SQL statements.

tbl_username

```
id  username
1   Adam
2   Bob
3   Chris
```

tbl_opportunity

[image: tbl_opportunity]

I got these two table, I would like the outcome like this

[image]

I tested with following sql, but the outcome is wrong

```
SELECT users.`username`, COUNT(`proposal`.name) AS `Pro Total Number Quotation`, CONCAT('RM', FORMAT(SUM(`proposal`.`amount`), 2)) AS pro_rm_amount, 
COUNT(`nego`.name) AS `nego Total Number Quotation`, CONCAT('RM', FORMAT(SUM(`nego`.`amount`), 2)) AS nego_rm_amount, 
COUNT(`cw`.name) AS `cw Total Number Quotation`, CONCAT('RM', FORMAT(SUM(`cw`.`amount`), 2)) AS cw_rm_amount,
COUNT(`cl`.name) AS `cl Total Number Quotation`, CONCAT('RM', FORMAT(SUM(`cl`.`amount`), 2)) AS cl_rm_amount

FROM tbl_username users
JOIN `tbl_opportunity` AS proposal ON (proposal.`user_id` = users.id AND proposal.`sales_stage` = 'Proposal' AND proposal.`deleted`=0 AND MONTH(`proposal`.date)= '1'
AND YEAR(`proposal`.date)= '2012')
LEFT JOIN `tbl_opportunity` AS nego ON (proposal.`user_id` = users.id AND proposal.`sales_stage` = 'Nego' AND nego.`deleted`=0 AND MONTH(`nego`.date)= '1'
AND YEAR(`nego`.date)= '2012')
LEFT JOIN `tbl_opportunity` AS cw ON (cw.`user_id` = users.id AND cw.`stage` = 'Win' AND cw.`deleted`=0 AND MONTH(`cw`.date)= '1'
AND YEAR(`cw`.date)= '2012')
LEFT JOIN `tbl_opportunity` AS cl ON (cl.`user_id` = users.id AND cl.`stage` = 'Lose' AND cl.`deleted`=0 AND MONTH(`cl`.date)= '1'
AND YEAR(`cl`.date)= '2012')

GROUP BY users.`username`
```

Comment: the sql statement and table a bit different due to I lazy to retype it again :p

Comment: so which one are you trying to get an answer for? The example tables or the tables and columns referenced in the query that you have tried? If you need a definitive answer I suggest you take the time to make your example table layout and data and your example query match.

Comment: Hi @Tom Mac, I had updated the sql statement to match the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused since the tables and columns that you have provided don't quite match those in the SQL that you have tried. Anyway, given the data & tables you have provided and the outcome you have specified this should help you out. Even if it doesn't it should serve as an example of how to use `SUM` in conjunction with `CASE` (a very handy SQL combination for flattening out data).

Give this a go:

```
select u.username,
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'proposal' then 1 else 0 end) as "Proposal Count"  ,
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'proposal' then amount else 0 end) as "Proposal Amount",
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'nego' then 1 else 0 end) as "Nego Count"  ,
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'nego' then amount else 0 end) as "Nego Amount",
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'win' then 1 else 0 end) as "Win Count"  ,
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'win' then amount else 0 end) as "Win Amount",
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'lose' then 1 else 0 end) as "Lose Count"  ,
sum(case when lower(stage) = 'lose' then amount else 0 end) as "Lose Amount"
from tbl_username u
inner join tbl_opportunity o on u.id = o.user_id
group by u.username;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Tom Mac, really appreciate your solution. My MySQL knowledge told me that my question only can be solved with join table, but you give a new solution and view to me. Thanks a lot!